# How to fill two arc in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have drawn *two arcs* as path like below,

```
 Path path = new Path();
 path.ArcTo(rc, (float)startArc, (float)(angle1 - startArc));
 path.ArcTo(innerrc,  (float)(angle - startArc), (float)startArc);
 canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

Now i need to fill those two arcs.

Any idea about this? !

[image]

Comment: `Paint#setStyle` ?

Comment: If i use setstyle as fill two arcs alone will be filled.But I need to fill those two arcs like closed path. 

The below is for iOS,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370841/how-to-fill-space-between-two-uibezierpaths/44984775#44984775

I need the same in android.

Comment: Edited my question. if i draw arcs with paint setstyle as fill two arc alone gets filled.

Comment: if you want two individual arc to be filled / closed use `addArc` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it and this works fine for me !

```
 Path path = new Path();
 paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
 path.MoveTo((float)xnew, (float)ynew);
 path.ArcTo(rc, (float)startArc, (float)(angle1 - startArc));
 path.LineTo((float)xnew1, (float)ynew1);
 path.ArcTo(innerrc,  (float)(angle - startArc), (float)startArc);
 path.LineTo((float)xnew, (float)ynew);
 canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```